# Разбить число на числа входящие в него и создав из них массив

Tags: java, массивы

Разбить число на числа входящие в него и создав из них массив.
Есть число `120`, нужен массив `{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},...,{119},{120}`.
Тип массива не важен.

 
Буду премного благодарен, если подскажете.

Comment: IntStream.range(1, 120+1).toArray();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно задание. Первое и второе предложения противоречат друг другу. Но если по примеру, то вот:

```java
int n = 120;
int[] arr = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    arr[i] = i + 1;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Очень лаконичный вариант это решения предложили в комментариях.

Comment: Все верно понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решение на стримах, предложенное в комментариях:

```java
int[] arr = IntStream.range(0, 120).map(i -> i + 1).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 119, 120]
```

Или проще можно:

```java
int[] arr = IntStream.range(1, 121).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 119, 120]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод [`IntStream.rangeClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) - обход значений из диапазона, включая конечные точки:

```java
int[] arr = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 120).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 119, 120]
```